# Alternative for onChange event for <select> tag in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm creating a Component that has multiple `<select>` tags. Based on the selected option it fetches options for the next tag. I'm using onChange event. The problem I'm facing is if there's only 1  option in then onChange is never triggered.

Is there any event in ReactJS, like `onSelect` that I can use to achieve this or, any better method?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/54oee43q/ The problem with this approach is, it's not generic. Believe me, I've tried both. Suppose user opens the options dropdown `onClick` will be triggered, here he/she is not selecting anything. when he/she is selecting anything, `onClick` in not called. When clicks again then we get the value. It's not the expected behaviour. He/she should click only once and function takes the value.

Comment: I would use `onChange` + `onFocus`, then call `.focus()` on the next select element after its options have been updated. If there's only one option, proceed to update the next element. Alternatively you could have the first option with empty value and text like `--choose--` so it would force the user to make a choice even if there's just one option to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not make the first option a disabled placeholder as follows:

```
<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
```

That way the the user would have to trigger a fetch.

If you require a default state you can handle this outside of the select box.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)